# error when setting up bash profile

Tags: ruby, bash

Hello I am a beginner programmer trying to set up a newer version of Ruby.  My bash profile looks like this:

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

and I'm getting this error every time I open a new tab in my terminal:

```
line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
line 2: `rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `if` however it's not needed. Just use:

```
 rbenv > /dev/null; eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

For the second line instead.

Comment: shouldn't that be `rbenv > /dev/null && eval "$(rbenv init -)"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

`which -s rbenv && eval "$(rbenv init -)"`

Comment: `eval` is necessary with `rbenv init -` because it outputs shell commands that need to be executed.

Comment: @chepner fair enough, It's still a valid answer, just removed the eval part